# throughput control via Sleep

Tags: c++, algorithm, sockets, networking, buffer

I have this code, the point is that I want to receive no more than 600Kbits/s using a UDP socket, I implemented an algorithm using duration during which we receive and the sleep command....

```
#if defined (WIN32)
#include <winsock2.h>

typedef int socklen_t;
#elif defined (linux)
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#define INVALID_SOCKET -1
#define SOCKET_ERROR -1
#define closesocket(s) close(s)
typedef int SOCKET;
typedef struct sockaddr_in SOCKADDR_IN;
typedef struct sockaddr SOCKADDR;
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>


 #define RCVBUFSIZE 4
#define PORT 4444
 #define ECHOMAX 255

int main(void)
 {
#if defined (WIN32)
    WSADATA WSAData;
    int erreur = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WSAData);
#else
    int erreur = 0;
#endif

int recvMsgSize;
char echoBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE];
//unsigned int echoStringLen;
//int bytesRcvd, totalBytesRcvd; //bytes received in a single recv()

SOCKET sock;
SOCKADDR_IN sin;
SOCKADDR_IN SenderAddr;
int SenderAddrSize = sizeof(SenderAddr);


if(!erreur)
{

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(4444);
   memset(&sin.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(sin.sin_zero));

     bind(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, sizeof(sin));

//totalBytesRcvd = 0;

printf("Received: ");

int speed_limit= 614400; //600Kbits/s
int one_second=1000;
int elapsed; //elapsed time
int transmit=0; // how much i receive during 'elapsed'
int expected_receive; //what I'm excpected to receive
int transmit_delta; //diference
int time_sleep; //how much to sleep
clock_t start_time= clock();

 for(;;)
{


    if((recvMsgSize=recvfrom(sock, echoBuffer,1024, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize)) > 0)
    {
            transmit+=recvMsgSize;
            clock_t tempo= clock();

            elapsed=(tempo-start_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        // Check moment speed every five second, you can choose any value
            if(elapsed>5)
            {
                start_time= tempo;
                expected_receive=speed_limit*elapsed/8;
                transmit_delta=expected_receive-transmit;

                if(transmit_delta>0)
                {
                    time_sleep=8*transmit_delta*one_second/speed_limit;
                    Sleep(time_sleep);
                }
                transmit=0;
            }
            echoBuffer[recvMsgSize]='\0';
            printf(echoBuffer);


    }

}
    printf("\n");
    getchar() ;

closesocket(sock);

    #if defined (WIN32)
        WSACleanup();
    #endif
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

the problem is that it receive the message but it blocks the receiving process from time to time...which I guess will cause loss of data especially when I'm using UDP...

any alternative solution is welcolme...

thanks in advance..

Comment: we always start from nothing.....to reach the top..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use non-blocking sockets with `select()` you can just ignore the data until you're ready to read it. Not reading data will cause the TCP connection to "slow down". However, this way you do **not** have exact control about the amount of data received. It's just an approximation. All techniques I know of that limit bandwidth in a more accurate way are implemented on the sender side.

Comment: what do you mean by non-blocking sockets?

Comment: thanks for the doc...but still don't get it, hwo can select function limit the throughput...it just allows selecting a socket and waiting a bunch of time for sth to happen...

Comment: If nothing happens you don't need to worry about controlling throughput. If data is ready to be read you can ignore it if your throughput is currently to high. The point is that select does not read any data. It just lets you know that data is available. TCP congestion handling will slow down the data transfer automatically if you don't read the data when it arrives.

Comment: I guess here the problem...I'm using UDP...If I do so...data will be lost!!

Answer (score 1):

Better not to sleep - just read and discard data while you are over the threshold, then resume processing it once you are ready to do so (after interval expires).

Comment: can you give much more explanation...for ex, how to discard data?

Comment: @fsidiosidi - you just read it the way you are now, but don't do anything with it.  This keeps the network pipe clear without any data being discarded in the stack.  In your example code, you would bypass the `printf`.  You could track the amount in bytes of ignored data to see if your threshold for ignoring it is reasonable.

Comment: but that will not limit the throughput..It will just discard arriving data...I want to receive no more than ex: 600kbits per seconde!!

Answer (score 1):

If the data is arriving over UDP, there is no way to reduce the throughput at the receiving end.  You'd have to tell the sending computer to send less data.  The receiver's only choice is the receive the UDP packets, or let them get dropped, and do something with them, or not.

If you use TCP, then the TCP protocol includes a built-in way to do what you want (called "source quench") ... the TCP protocol layer of the receiver will send a message to the sender telling the sender to slow down if the receiver is having problems keeping up.  (and you can influence whether "the receiver is having problems keeping up" by reading the data slower than usual, if you want).

Comment: but if we assume using UDP and the sender sends data by the throughput we want...then if we receive this data with the same throughput, I think we will get less loss...what do u think?